# How do I add an image taken by camera or galery to a button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using an `UIImagePickerController` to choose a source to take a picture from. This picture should be set to an `UIButton`.

I know you can add an `UIImage` to an `UIButton` by string, like 
`someButton.setImage(UIImage(named:...))`, but I need to set it by a variable which I create with taking the picture.

```
@IBOutlet weak var addPictureOutlet: UIButton!

func chooseSource() {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self


    let kameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kamera",
                                     style: .default) { (action) in
                                        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                                        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let libraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Galerie",
                                      style: .default) { (action) in
                                        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                                        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: .cancel)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quelle",
                                  message: "Wählen sie eine Quelle für die Klausur.",
                                  preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(kameraAction)
    alert.addAction(libraryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true) {

    }
}

@IBAction func addPicture(_ sender: UIButton) {

    chooseSource()

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image1 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        addPictureOutlet.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I've tried this, but I can't really figure out why it doesn't work, there is no error while compiling or running and the `UIImage` of the `UIButton` does not change.

Comment: First check the variable is geeting the input of image or it is nill

Comment: The imagePicker function is never called.

Comment: i think you are missing delegate , see my below answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use like that. You cannot use a func in an action.

```
@IBOutlet weak var addPictureOutlet: UIButton!

    func chooseSource() {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self


        let kameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kamera",
                                         style: .default) { (action) in
                                            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                                            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let libraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Galerie",
                                          style: .default) { (action) in
                                            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                                            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: .cancel)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quelle",
                                      message: "Wählen sie eine Quelle für die Klausur.",
                                      preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(kameraAction)
        alert.addAction(libraryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true) {

        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image1 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        addPictureOutlet.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func addPicture(_ sender: UIButton) {
        chooseSource()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have multiple UIButtons which need this function and I can't work with sender and I also wanna save up some redundant lines of code.

Comment: Edit: I'm also stuck with your code when you have to choose between taking or using the picture, the buttons don't work, still no error.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is not going into imagePicker method, it seems you have missed delegate to work imagePicker method properly

Add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and create a variable to assign UIImagePickerController `var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()`
and set `imagePicker.delegate = self`

Comment: I already had the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate at the top of the whole class. Also a variable is set to assign the UIImagePickerController, just look at the code.